# img: hover works in jsbin but not working locally?

Tags: html, css

Hi I could use some help with this, in jsbin buttons change color on hover as they should but locally it does not work; there is no color change. At first I thought it was me but the exact same thing happens when I copy the [instructors code](http://www.cocotuts.com/create-an-html5-video-player-scratch) (it was from a short [Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/html5-video-player/)) Here is my code:

```
             `http://output.jsbin.com/cehiwok `
img {
background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
img:hover {
background-color: rgb(50, 170, 220);
}
img, #pbar-container, #sbar-container {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any image in html?

Comment: Add your html or best thing would be to create a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net//

Comment: The css is ok, it works only with png or gif images, I assume that you didn't change the images to jpg, did you?